# Getting error Cannot convert Generic.Comparer<Pair> to Generic.IComparer<int> while comparing two objects in a priority queue in c# using lambda ex

Tags: c#, lambda, priority-queue, icomparer

I have a pair class.

```
public class Pair
{
    public int freq;
    public int coolTime;
    
    public Pair(int freq, int coolTime)
    {
        this.freq = freq;
        this.coolTime = coolTime;
    }
}
```

I want to create a priority queue with a custom comparer to make it a maxheap. I am trying to do it using lambda. I am not understanding where is the problem. Here are the things that I have tried.

```
 var pq = new PriorityQueue<Pair, int>(Comparer<Pair>.Create((x, y) => y.freq.CompareTo(x.freq)));
```

I know I am making some silly mistake but I am not sure what it is. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: This is th error I am getting at compile time.
[image]

Comment: Can you articulate the problem you're facing?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: I added the image to the question to show the issue.

Comment: Adding the error to your question as text would be better.

Comment: Also, the error message is pretty clear: _"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<Pair>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<int>?'."_. What is the issue you're facing in understanding it?

Comment: My doubt is how to create the comparer using lambda for the pair class to implement a maxheap on the basis of the freq attribute.

Comment: Where does the value of the `int` in your priority queue come from? Is that not the frequency?

Comment: Yes, the int(which determines the priority) is coming from the frequency.

Comment: `y.CompareTo(x)` is going to give you reverse order, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparer for `PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>` compares the priority, not the element. This is what the error message is telling you.

Change your code to compare the priority like this:

```cs
var pq = new PriorityQueue<Pair, int>(Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)));
```

[Priority Queue Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-priorityqueue-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-icomparer((-1))))

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thanks!